# Is $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$ irrational?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, irrational-numbers

> Q: Is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$$ irrational?

Here $p_n$ is the nth prime.

$$S_1= \frac{.9}{p_1}+\frac{.8}{p_2}+\frac{.7}{p_3}+...+\frac{.1}{p_9} $$

$$ S_2=\frac{.99}{p_1}+\frac{.98}{p_2}+\frac{.97}{p_3}+...+\frac{.01}{p_{99}} $$

$$ S_3= \frac{.999}{p_1}+\frac{.998}{p_2}+\frac{.997}{p_3}+...+\frac{.001}{p_{999}} $$

$$ ... $$

I think it is, because if you keep adding zeros to make the numerators smaller while retaining equal space among successive numerators, the period of the resultant rational sum extends to infinity, which would mean in limit form, $S$ would approach an irrational number. How can I formally prove this?

Comment: Are you sure the limit isn’t 0? I’m just asking, maybe there’s some reason that it obviously isn’t that I cannot see.

Comment: You might be able to get a decent estimate of $S_n$ using the prime number theorem (or "density of primes"). Have you done that? I think that this might support a limit of either $0$ or $\infty$, rather than some irrational. Certainly your argument for irrationality is flawed.

Comment: @JohnHughes I'll try using the PNT thanks

Comment: I made a mistake in the question...the numerators are in the opposite order

Comment: there is an edit button, so you could edit your question, to bring it in the form you intended (I do not understand your comment about numerators in opposite order). But I see you also accepted an answer (apparently not to the question that you intended?). Or, if you think you have a good question and could state it clearly, and show what you have attempted and why it might be interesting or relevant, then you may want to post it separately. Why would you ask people if you could edit your question, how would they know what you intended to ask?

Comment: Changing a question after you've already got multiple answers is a bit rude: it makes all the answerers look like idiots for answering the wrong question. Better to ask a NEW question -- there's no cost to doing so. You can even include a pointer back to the current one so that folks don't immediately assume that you're just re-posting. Fortunately @ChristianBlatter's answer is correct either way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over p_k}$ of the reciprocals of the primes diverges, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes). Since
$$S_n>{1\over2}\sum_{k=1}^{10^n/2}{1\over p_k}\qquad(n\geq1)$$
it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially you're averaging $j/p_j$ for $j$ from $1$ to $10^n$.  Since $j/p_j \to 0$ as $j \to \infty$, your limit will be $0$.

EDIT: For the new sequence, by the monotone convergence theorem for sums your limit is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/p_n$, which is $\infty$.

Comment: There is another factor of $10^{-n}$ which I think is needed to make the limit $0$.

Comment: @RossMillikan and Robert I. Can I edit the question, I made a mistake

Answer (score 2):

**Not an answer, but a strong suggestion**

Suppose you instead look at your series not just for powers of 10, but others as well, so that your first sum gets renamed 
$$
S_{10} = \frac{1}{10} \frac{1}{p_1} + \frac{2}{10} \frac{1}{p_2} + \ldots + \frac{10-1}{10} \frac{1}{p_{10-1}}. 
$$
Then the general form is 
$$
S_k = \frac{1}{k} \frac{1}{p_1} + \ldots + \frac{k-1}{k} \frac{1}{p_{k-1}} = \frac{1}{k} \left(1 \cdot \frac{1}{p_1} + \ldots + (k-1) \cdot \frac{1}{p_{k-1}} \right ).
$$
The density of primes is roughly $\frac{\log n}{n}$, so the $n$th prime is roughly $n \log n$. So let's replace all those terms with estimates to get
$$
S_k \approx \frac{1}{k} \left(1 \cdot \frac{1}{p_1} + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2 \ln 2}\ldots + (k-1) \cdot \frac{1}{(k-1) \ln (k-1)} \right ). 
$$
Lots of terms cancel, and we get

$$
S_k \approx \frac{1}{k} \left(1 \cdot \frac{1}{p_1} +  \frac{1}{ \ln 2}\ldots +  \frac{1}{\ln (k-1)} \right ). 
$$
Now the inside sum consists of about $k$ terms whose average value is about $\frac{1}{ln \frac{k}{2}}$ (I admit this is pretty crude as an estimate!), and when we multiply by $1/k$, we find that $S_k$ is approximately (up to a multiplicative constant) $\frac{1}{\ln k}$, which tends to zero as $k \to \infty$.

In short: the sequence appears to approach a very rational number, namely zero.